# While decrypting SAML response using xmlCipher.doFinal() not getting expected result of decrypted cipher data

Tags: encryption, onelogin

```
public static void decryptElement(Element encryptedDataElement, PrivateKey inputKey) {

    try {
        Init.init();

        XMLCipher xmlCipher = XMLCipher.getInstance();
        xmlCipher.init(XMLCipher.DECRYPT_MODE, inputKey);


        NodeList keyInfoInEncData = encryptedDataElement.getElementsByTagNameNS(Constants.NS_DS, "KeyInfo");
        System.out.println("keyInfoInEncData"+keyInfoInEncData.item(0).getNodeName());
        if (keyInfoInEncData.getLength() == 0) {
            throw new ValidationError("No KeyInfo inside EncryptedData element", ValidationError.KEYINFO_NOT_FOUND_IN_ENCRYPTED_DATA);
        }

        NodeList childs = keyInfoInEncData.item(0).getChildNodes();
        for (int i=0; i < childs.getLength(); i++) {
            if (childs.item(i).getLocalName() != null && childs.item(i).getLocalName().equals("RetrievalMethod")) {
                Element retrievalMethodElem = (Element)childs.item(i);
                if (!retrievalMethodElem.getAttribute("Type").equals("http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#EncryptedKey")) {
                    throw new ValidationError("Unsupported Retrieval Method found", ValidationError.UNSUPPORTED_RETRIEVAL_METHOD);
                }

                String uri = retrievalMethodElem.getAttribute("URI").substring(1);

                System.out.println("URI"+uri);

                NodeList encryptedKeyNodes = ((Element) encryptedDataElement.getParentNode()).getElementsByTagNameNS(Constants.NS_XENC, "EncryptedKey");
                for (int j=0; j < encryptedKeyNodes.getLength(); j++) {
                    if (((Element)encryptedKeyNodes.item(j)).getAttribute("Id").equals(uri)) {
                        keyInfoInEncData.item(0).replaceChild(encryptedKeyNodes.item(j), childs.item(i));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        NodeList node=encryptedDataElement.getChildNodes().item(2).getChildNodes();
        xmlCipher.setKEK(inputKey);
        xmlCipher.**doFinal**(encryptedDataElement.getOwnerDocument(), encryptedDataElement, false);            
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.warn("Error executing decryption: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Above code is the reference.

My response is having Cipher value. Need to *decrypt* the cipher value to get the mail ID.

I have Encrypted data Element.I am passing the encrypted data element to `decryptElement(encryptedDataElement)` and my private `RSA Key` a method.
Do final is not working as expected.Not event getting any logs.

Kindly review and help me to get the decrypt data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a visit into the element which is going through decrypt.
Instead of that i give Element encryptedData = (Element) EncryptedIdNodes.item(0);

Encryption is working fine.